# Determine the value of C so that L1 is Parallel to L2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Consider the following lines given below. Assume $C$ is a constant

- $L_1: Cy-2 x=11 $
- $L_2: (C+1)x+6y-4=0 $
- $L_3: (C-6)x=2y+5 $

**a)** Determine the value(s) of $C$ so that $L_1$ is parallel to $L_2$

**b)** Determine the value(s) of $C$ $L_2$ is perpendicular to $L_3 $

**c)** Does there exist a value of $C$ so that $L_1$ is parallel to $L_2$ AND $L_2$ is perpendicular to $L_3$?

What I've tried:

$$y=mx+b$$

- $L1: m=2/C b= 11/c$
- $L2: m= -(C+1)/6 b=4/6$
- $L3: m= (C-6)/2  b= -5/2$

please help, I don't know what to do next!

Comment: Note that if you want use angular coefficients we have $m_1=\frac 2 C$, $m_2=-\frac{C+1}6$ and $m_3=-\frac{C-6}2$

Comment: Are you sure that line is not  $L_1: Cx-2 y=11$?

Comment: No i'm sure the paper says Cy-2x=11. This doesn't make sense that it would have no solution

Comment: In that case point 1 has not a solution but I think it is a typo. For $L_1=Cx-2y=11$ we would obtain $\frac{C}{-2}=\frac{C+1}{6} \iff 6C=-2C-2 \implies C=-\frac14$

Comment: Thank you, I'll check with my teacher.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that given two lines

**1.** $a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ in implicit form or $y=m_1x+n_1$ in explicit form

**2.** $a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$ in implicit form or $y=m_2x+n_2$ in explicit form

they are

- parallel if $(a_1,b_1)=k(a_2,b_2)$ that is $\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a_2}{b_2}$ for $b_i\neq 0$ that is $m_1=m_2$
- perpendicular if $a_1a_2+b_1b_2=0$ that is $m_1\cdot m_2=-1$

Therefore for point $a)$ we have

$$\frac{-2}{C}=\frac{C+1}{6} \iff C^2+C+12=0 \implies C=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-48}}{2}$$

which means that there is not solution